# Rails ActiveRecord query ForeignKey except column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models: User and Address.

A User `has_many` addresses.

How can I produce JSON for a user, including their addresses, but omit the country from each address?

I have tried:

```
Users.all.to_json(:include => :addresses, :except => :country)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `except` option as part of the `addresses` key:

```
Users.all.to_json(
  include: {
    addresses: {
      except: :country
    }
  }
)
```